# How to calculate eigen values and vectors of a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I have a square matrix C,of which I have to find the eigen values and eigen vectors.

```
C =

     2    -1    -1     0
    -1     3    -1    -1
    -1    -1     3    -1
     0    -1    -1     2
```

When I use the function eig() such that,
 [V,D]=eig(C,'nobalance')
This is the output of V and D that I get:

```
V =

   -0.5000    0.7071    0.4914   -0.0924
   -0.5000   -0.0000   -0.3607    0.7874
   -0.5000   -0.0000   -0.6221   -0.6025
   -0.5000   -0.7071    0.4914   -0.0924

D =

   -0.0000         0         0         0
         0    2.0000         0         0
         0         0    4.0000         0
         0         0         0    4.0000
```

But when I give the same matrix C at an online matrix calculator(http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/), the corresponding eigen values and vectors that I get are as follows:

```
Eigenvalues:

(0.000,0.000i)
(2.000,0.000i)
(4.000,0.000i)
(4.000,0.000i)

Eigenvectors:

( 0.500, 0.000i) ( 0.707, 0.000i) ( 0.500, 0.000i) (-0.308, 0.000i)
( 0.500, 0.000i) ( 0.000, 0.000i) (-0.500, 0.000i) (-0.250, 0.000i)
( 0.500, 0.000i) ( 0.000, 0.000i) (-0.500, 0.000i) ( 0.865, 0.000i)
( 0.500, 0.000i) (-0.707, 0.000i) ( 0.500, 0.000i) (-0.308, 0.000i)
```

Can you tell me why there is a difference in values at the two cases?Are the values returned  by the eig function in matlab correct?Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find out simply by trying to reconstruct the matrix from V and D...

Comment: Incidentally, the matlab pages say that the balanceOption is ignored in cases where the input matrix is symmetric http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/eig.html#inputarg_balanceOption

Comment: Yes,I could reconstruct the matrix C. But again, My project deals with eigen vectors calculated based on their signs. So when I gave the input C to the online calculater mentioned in the url, the signs of the figures are seen to be different. So wouldn't that be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the eigenvalues are the same. The eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue 4 are different because that eigenvalue has multiplicity=2 and therefore its space of eigenvectors is two-dimensional. I.e., a numerical eigenvector solver could come up with any pair of linear independent vectors in that 2-dimensional space.

Comment: The eigen values are not the same. The first element in D is -0.000 whereas from the calculator it is 0.000,0.000i. The signs are different.

Comment: But here when I print D(1,1) instead of -0.000 I am getting -1.2958e-015. Why is that?

Comment: Also no matter what my input to the function is, I am always getting the value of D(1,1) as -0.000

Comment: @Geethu Your main confusion is caused by simple rounding errors. 1.2958e-015 on a scale of 0 to 4 simply means 0. The same holds if it is negative.

Comment: @Geethu The format in which MATLAB displays numbers on the screen can be different depending on whether it is part of the display of an array of numbers, or whether it is an individual scalar. MATLAB tries to choose a format that best displays all numbers in the list. The display is also affected by the `format` command. Enter `format long` at the command line and redisplay D, to see the effect.